# Change React component if route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

i'm using react-redux-router.
I have the following code:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" component={Product} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I want to show in App component different data when my route is "/" and when my route is "/product/:id". How can I keep track of the change of route in component App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `react-router-redux`'s `syncHistory` middleware to keep route in store. Then you can utilize `connect` in App component to read pathname from `state.routing.location.pathname` and push it to props.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same idea. And in component check via regular expressions.

Comment: Easier would be something like `state.routing.location.pathname.split("/").indexOf(foo) > -1`

Edit: that is unless you want to check for number parameter, of course... Regular expressions will work fine :) 

If I helped you, please consider voting up :) thanks